# Bootstrap Grid elements order (up and below another element)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to get my ordering right with Bootstrap. I'm either stuck vertically or horizontally.

Desktop displays like:

[ - 2 - ][ 1 ]
[ - 2 - ][ 3 ]
[ - 2 - ]

Mobile should display like:

[ - 1 - ]
[ - 2 - ]
[ - 2 - ]
[ - 2 - ]
[ - 3 - ]

whereas [ 2 ] is a single element, just higher.

This is how far I got. Which is obviously wrong, because it looks good on desktop but not on mobile.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box-a col-sm-12">1</div>
            <div class="box-b col-sm-12">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-c col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6L2otx3w/

I get stuck on the columns. But if I try mobile first:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 box-a"> 1</div>
      <div class="box-c col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2</div>
    </div>
   <div class="row">   
     <div class="box-b col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8"> 3</div> 
   </div>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvdf5p8k/

I get stuck on the rows (looks fine on mobile but not on desktop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by pulling the columns and setting them all to 12 columns when on mobile (xs). You can change the `sm` breakpoints to whatever you'd like.

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heraldo/yvdf5p8k/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box-a col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right"> 1</div>
        <div class="box-c col-xs-12 col-sm-8 pull-left">2</div>
        <div class="box-b col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right"> 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked fine <br><br>Say: where can i find documentation about "pull-right" & "pull-left"? unlinke "col-xx-push-x" i dont find it at bootstrap-documentation.

Comment: @Elias - They're simple float classes. You can find them under "Quick floats" in the CSS tab. Link here: https://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats. Also, if this answer worked, don't forget to mark it as accepted for anyone else looking for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think bootstrap do not have ability do that.

[ - 2 - ][ 1 ]

[ - 2 - ][ 3 ]

[ - 2 - ]

mobile should display like:

[ - 1 - ]

[ - 2 - ]

[ - 2 - ]

[ - 2 - ]

[ - 3 - ]

---

If like this is ok.

[ - 2a - ][ 1 ]

[ - 2b - ][ 3 ]

[ - 2c - ][ 4 ]

mobile should display like:

[ - 1 - ]

[ - 2a - ]

[ - 3  - ]

[ - 2b - ]

[ - 4  - ]

[ - 2c - ]

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="bg-primary col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">1</div>
    <div class="bg-danger col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2a</div>
    <div class="bg-warning col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">3</div>
    <div class="bg-success col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2b</div>
    <div class="bg-primary col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">4</div>
    <div class="bg-info col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

i tried to solve it only by using default classes that bootstrap give to us but i coudn't find a way in so i opted to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5ztsq47u/2/):

> HTML

As you can see **row "3"** is duplicated for making it orderable on mobile.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box-a col-sm-12">1</div>
                <div class="box-b col-sm-12">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-c col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">2</div>
        <div class="box-b2 col-xs-12">3</div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

I did it by adding **display none** to *box-b* on mobile and **display none** to *box-b2* on desktop.

```
.box-b { background-color: lavender; display:none; }
.box-b2 { background-color: lavender; }
.box-c { background-color: orange; height: 60px;}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .box-b{
    display:block;
  }
 .box-b2{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Tell me please if it may help you and if it was as you wanted, thank you.

Comment: Hey Sid, it does work but I wanted to avoid duplicates and hiding elements. That's why I find the other answer a little more elegant.